# Does playing as different heroes change anything?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one

I'm about to start my first game, and I noticed I can choose to play as Ratchet, Clank, Captain Qwark, or Dr. Nefarious.

Is this just a cosmetic choice, or are there actual gameplay differences depending on which character I choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each hero has a unique weapon that only he can use:

- Ratchet: the doppelbanger same as the Decoy Glove from the first and second games throw out a dummy to distract the enemies
- Clank: zoni blaster slows down time
- Qwark: quantum deflector is an ultimate defense and great for rushing in to smash everything
- Nefarious: cloaker lets you become invisible

Comment: When do you get these weapons?

Comment: as you play along normally early to midway through but I'd have to check exactly when